# Как расставить блоки равномерно

Tags: css3

Я конечно извиняюсь,может код и абы-как сделан.Но почти всё закончил.
И хотел расположить равномерно 9 блоков в блоке.Можно подогнать более-менее,но хочется ровнее.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
header{background-color: #000;
    color:#91949f;
    height:42px;
    width:100%;}
ul {list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;}
li {float: left;}
li a, .dropbtn, #profil a{color:#bbbab8;font-size:1.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;}
.dropdown-content a {
    color:gray;background-color:black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color:gray;color:#fff;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
li a:hover, #profil a:hover{background-color:#2e2f2f;color:#fff;}
#profil{float:right;}
#tLogo{float: left;padding: 5px;}
.zagolovok{background-color:gray;text-align:center;width:100%;}
center{width:80%;background-color:#c18d51;
    ;height:900px;margin:;}
aside{float:right;width:20%;height:900px;
  text-align:center;background-color:#6392cc;}
footer{color:#fff;background-color:black;height:40px;
  text-align:center;}
.bok{width:90%;margin:5%;background-color:#dcdae8;height:20%;}
.nok{background-color:#d675ab;border-radius:10px;width:30%;height:28%;
  margin:1%;float:left;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1.0>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TatuN</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  <link href="T.png" rel="chortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <img id="tLogo" src="TTT.jpg" alt="ttt"/>
      <li><a href="#home">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#links">Ссылки</a></li>
      <li><a href="#onas">Связь</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Ярлыки</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <div id="profil">
          <a href="">Профиль</a>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="zagolovok"><h1>Заголовок</h1></div>
  <aside>Правый блок
    <div class="bok">1</div>
    <div class="bok">2</div>
    <div class="bok">3</div>
    <div class="bok">4</div>
  </aside>
  <center><div class="vok"><h2>Контент</h2></div>
      <div class="nok">kkl1</div>
      <div class="nok">kj2</div>
      <div class="nok">qw3</div>
      <div class="nok">we4</div>
      <div class="nok">re1</div>
      <div class="nok">as2</div>
      <div class="nok">73</div>
      <div class="nok">84</div>
      <div class="nok">92</div>
  </center>
  <footer>Футер</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример

1. Используем [calc](https://webref.ru/css/value/calc) -  `width: calc(100% / 3 - 2%);`

   а) делим ширину контейнера на количество блоков - 100% / 3

   б) чтобы поместить блоки необходимо отнять отступ для каждого блока (1% + 1%), т.к.
     100% + margin% > 100%

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper{ 
  border: 1px solid #444;  
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 1%;
}
.item{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;  
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 2%); 
  margin: 1%;  
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 15px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
   <div class="item">6</div>
   <div class="item">7</div>
   <div class="item">8</div>
   <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Во, то что надо. Конечно я думал есть какой-нибудь слово чтоб не высчитывать калькуляцию.

Comment: Но, меня смущает min-height в примере,тогда блоки сверху располагаются,а снизу много места остаётся.Я поставил 30%,выглядит нормально.

Comment: @tatunserg min-height - это для примера

Comment: Ага, как только сделал текст видимым,и убрал padding, всё перемешалось

Comment: @tatunserg - убрал padding, сделал текст видиммым - все осталось на месте https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/mqmzyzs5/

Comment: Тут нормально.У меня же бред какой-то выходил.И расстояние между блоками двойное было.И снизу в зависимости от выставленной высоты: то оставалось место,то вылазило за нижнюю границу.

Comment: box-sizing: border-box  используете?

Comment: Да, всё делал как в примере. Я так понял это от размера окна браузера зависело, я смотрел сразу в окне,а потом на полный. Хотя делал адаптив,и браузер - хром.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант. Смысл в том, что элементы внутри блока имеют свойство `display` со значением 'inline-block'. И если задать родительскому блоку свойство `text-align` со значением `center`, то все элементы внутри будут располагаться по центру. Советую почитать [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/238449/) про центрирование элементов.

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 900px;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
}

.item{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1.0>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TatuN</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
  <link href="T.png" rel="chortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
   <div class="item">6</div>
   <div class="item">7</div>
   <div class="item">8</div>
   <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: text-align:center - ставит текст в блоках по середине,но не блоки.

Comment: Решил,вроде бы: только вручную подогнал высоту ширину,отступы. И без float:left ничего не вышло бы.А пример не дал  результата,только текст стал посредине.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу еще вариант с флексами...

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #91949f;
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn,
#profil a {
  color: #bbbab8;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: gray;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

li a:hover,
#profil a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2f2f;
  color: #fff;
}

#profil {
  float: right;
}

#tLogo {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.zagolovok {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

center {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #c18d51;
  height: 900px;
  /*  */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

aside {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #6392cc;
}

footer {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bok {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
  background-color: #dcdae8;
  height: 20%;
}

.nok {
  background-color: #d675ab;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 2%);
  height: calc(100% / 3 - 2% - 20px);
  margin: 1%;
  /*float: left;*/
}
/*  */
.vok {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1.0>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TatuN</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link href="T.png" rel="chortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <img id="tLogo" src="TTT.jpg" alt="ttt" />
      <li><a href="#home">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#links">Ссылки</a></li>
      <li><a href="#onas">Связь</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Ярлыки</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <div id="profil">
        <a href="">Профиль</a>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="zagolovok">
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  </div>
  <aside>Правый блок
    <div class="bok">1</div>
    <div class="bok">2</div>
    <div class="bok">3</div>
    <div class="bok">4</div>
  </aside>
  <center>
    <div class="vok">
      <h2>Контент</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="nok">kkl1</div>
    <div class="nok">kj2</div>
    <div class="nok">qw3</div>
    <div class="nok">we4</div>
    <div class="nok">re1</div>
    <div class="nok">as2</div>
    <div class="nok">73</div>
    <div class="nok">84</div>
    <div class="nok">92</div>
  </center>
  <footer>Футер</footer>
</body>

</html>
```